# Use 'not' instead of '!' in R

Tags: r, operator-keyword, unary-operator

I would like R to be more pythonic. One of the steps for transforming it would be the use of 'not' instead of '!'. I hope this does not need writing of C++ and compiling etc, or does it?

Functionality: "!TRUE" should equal "not TRUE".

If you know where to start, please point me there.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-March/048680.html

Comment: ... based on that comment thread, it seems your request is impossible without modifying the parser (i.e., it's not possible to define custom unary operators).

Comment: If you want python use python ... I've voted to close this question as being too broad.

Comment: Well, it does pose a clearly defined programming question ... we can disagree about whether it's a good idea, but it's clearly stated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You better embrace the R way. Why all the effort for such a small thing? If you want Python, stick with Python. Besides, it is REALLY common to have `!` act as "not" in other programming languages.

Anyway, this is something that allows the use of "not", but it will involve parentheses (the Arrr! way)

```
not <- function(x) { !x }

if (not(FALSE)) { print(1) }
[1] 1
```

In my opinion this is far worse than `!`.

And I can hear you thinking "but I would like to have `if x is not in y:`", but please, that would be the same as suggesting I'd want a way for Python not to need indenting.

The idea is that you learn a language, you do not change a language to suit an individual's needs. What will happen with others using your code?

Comment: Those who would use my code would have code that is nicely readable as in Python. They would get some kind of library that defines the 'not' as well as some other nice functionality and approaches from Python. The parentheses are exactly why I posted the question.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, but I think @Dualinity's answer is the best you're likely to do unless you do want to take on the highly non-trivial task of making your own modified version of the base R code that modifies the parser  ...

Comment: Yes, I am not going to modify the parser. Reading the answer I realised that it's not only the '!' but the if has parentheses as well. I guess I have to learn to like "if (!var) ...". :)